# Populate image after postback problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the following problem:

On button click I want to populate an image source and show an image inside a ModalPopupExtender.
In order to open the ModalPopupExtender I call `__doPostBack` that cause UpdatePanel to do postback and show appropriate View with the image inside it.

```
 <script src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.pageLoad = function () {
        $addHandler($get('btn1'), 'click', function (e) {
            __doPostBack('pbcTest', '');
            // setTimeout("PopulateImage()", 100);
            PopulateImage();
            $find('<%=mpePopup.ClientID%>').show();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }

    function PopulateImage() {
        $(".testImage").attr("src", "6.jpg");
    }

</script>

<ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="false">
    </ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <button id="btn1"> Click</button>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbTest" runat="server" Text="show popup" Style="display: none;" />
    <ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="mpePopup" TargetControlID="lbTest"
        PopupControlID="pnlPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="lbClose" />
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlPopup" CssClass="modalPopup">
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbClose">Close</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:MultiView runat="server" ID="mvPopup">
                    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                        <img class="testImage" />
                    </asp:View>
                </asp:MultiView>
                <cs:PostBackControl runat="server" ID="pbcTest" OnCallBack="pbcTest_CallBack" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>

 protected void pbcTest_CallBack(object sender, CallBackEventArgs e)
    {
        mvPopup.ActiveViewIndex = 0; 
    }
```

If after `__doPostBack` I call immediately `PopulateImage()`, the image is empty (although `PopulateImage()` is called and the image appears for a while, but after that disappears,  it's possible to see in firebug).

But if I put a timeout `setTimeout("PopulateImage()", 100);` image shows up.

What could be the cause of such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to always call `PopulateImage();` after the `UpdatePanel` has completed a refresh you should do it by registering the function to execute after the `UpdatePanel` has loaded.  You can register your function by doing the following in javascript when your page is loaded:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_pageLoaded(PopulateImage);
```

I think you might be experiencing a synchronization issue where you `UpdatePanel` refresh is happening AFTER your `PopulateImage()` code has run so it replaces it.

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right. Actually I've added Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler); and it works fine.